# Excel formula for column of last negative value in range (no array formulas)

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I have an Excel formula to find the column number of the last cell with a negative value in a row.
The problem is that it's an array formula, and the tool I need to use to create the spreadsheet (Apache POI SXSSF) doesn't support array formulas.

The values in the row are not ordered in any way.

The array formula that works when I make the spreadsheet by hand is

```
{=MATCH(2,1/(B18:M18<0))}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result with a normal formula?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=MATCH(2,1/MMULT(1,-(B18:M18<0)))
```

**Explanation**

If the original formula is entered normally, the range `B18:M18` is evaluated using implicit intersection (eg if entered in `C5` it evaluates as `=MATCH(2,1/(C18<0))` which returns `#N/A`). Entering the formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER means that the range is evaluated as an array and not a single cell range.

`MMULT` is one of only a few functions that can return an array from a range of values. To make use of it here we first need to convert the array of boolean values to numbers using `-(B1:B18<0)` (or with `N` in place of `-`). Next we pre-multiply by `1` (i.e. a 1x1 matrix) to return the same array as if it had been array-evaluated. This works for horizontal arrays, for vertical arrays we need to post-multiply by 1 which means switching the arguments around.

This method works quite generally. As another example consider finding the largest negative value in the range using the formula `=MAX(IF(B1:B18<0,B1:B18))`. Again replacing `B1:B18<0` by `MMULT(1,-(B1:B18<0))` removes the need for array-entry. Without trying to come up with a totally different formula, i don't know of any other way to do this.

Comment: OP's array formula works. Your formula never fails :) but this doesn't work for me.. Am I missing something?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, have switched the arguments around - hopefully that fixes it.

Comment: I normally use INDEX like this `=MATCH(2,INDEX(1/(B18:M18<0),0))`

Comment: Interesting, i didn't know INDEX would work like that. I had tried `1/INDEX(...,0)` without success. `MMULT` will return an error if there are any error values in the range which may or may not be desired.

Comment: i've added further explanation above